# Creating admin grid for custom eav model using ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, eav

I have created a UI component to represent the data in my custom eav model.
But it didn't work at all. The spinning animation didn't disappear and my page looks like this

[image]

I checked all the log file and it didn't have any php error. I checked console tab in my browser too and it didn't have any javascript error.

This is my `entity table`
[image]

This is my `ui component code`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_vendor_index.vendor_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_vendor_index.vendor_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">vendor_vendor_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add new Vendor</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="vendor_grid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" path="mui/index/render" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="vendor_vendor_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">ID</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

This is my `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="{Namespace}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor\Grid\Collection"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">namespace_vendor_entity</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">{Namespace}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendor_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">{Namespace}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This is my layout code. The ui component file name is `vendor_listing.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="formkey"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="vendor_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please tell me why it's not working and how can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make path to resourcemodel instead of collection:

> write {Namespace}{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor
>   instead of {Namespace}{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor\Collection

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="{Namespace}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor\Grid\Collection"
             type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">namespace_vendor_entity</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">{Namespace}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vendor_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">{Namespace}\{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: it didn't work after I changed it to `{Namespace}{ModuleName}\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor`

Comment: Have you check after clearing cache and cookie or after removing generated folder?

Comment: Yes. I run the command `setup:upgrade`, `cache:flus` and `cache:clean` but it's still the same

Comment: @thanhdv2811 Can you please post your layout file code here

Comment: I updated my layout to the question. When I replaced `vendor_listing` with `customer_listing`, I saw the customer grid show up. So I'm sure that my ui component had problem

Comment: you have to replace vendor_vendor_index.vendor_grid_data_source with vendor_listing.vendor_grid_data_source

Comment: It works. Can you explain why it's `vendor_listing`?

Comment: Here better explain please go through document:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-listing-grid.html

And please voted up if you found my answer useful
Thanks

Comment: Can you please help me here ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/263108/60509